# Maschke's theorem for group of unipotent matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Maschke's theorem states that: Let $G$ be a finite group, $K$ a field whose characteristic does not divide the order of $G$, $V$ a $K$-vector space of finite dimension and $\rho:G\to {\rm GL}(V)$ a representation of $G$. If $W$ is a $G$-invariant vector space of $V$, then there exists a $G$-invariant complement $W'$ such that $V=W\oplus W'$.

I was wondering if someone could tell me if the finite group $G$ in the theorem can be replaced by the subgroup of unipotent matrices of $GL_n(K)$? where $K$ is any algebraically closed field. Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the action of the unipotent subgroup on $K^n$ or are you asking "for any $V$ and any morphism from unipotent matrices to $GL(V)$, bla" ?

Comment: For this question, I am asking the latter

Comment: Then do you require that $K$ be finite and that the field we act on (which may a priori be different from $K$) has a characteristic that does not divide the order of the unipotent matrices ?

Comment: I was wondering about any algebraically closed field including char $0$ (if some analogous statement was out there for this case)

Comment: But are you specifically after $K$-representations of $Uni(K)$ or are you also considering $k$-representations of $Uni(K)$ for some other field $k$ ?

Comment: @Max For this question, I was wondering about the former.